# How to get json response from webapi in particular format

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

In my application default json result returning from webapi is something like this-

```
 [{"Id":1,"Name":"Nayas","Email":"nayas@gmail.com"},   {"Id":2,"Name":"Ramesh","Email":"ramesh@gmail.com"}].
```

I want this to be in the following format

```
 {
"success": true,
"users": [
    {"id": 1, "name": 'Ed',    "email": "ed@sencha.com"},
     {"id": 2, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com"}
]
}
```

key value pair

Here is my action method

```
public IEnumerable<User>GetUserList()
{ 
    return userlist;
}
```

and my model

```
public class User 
{ 
    [Key] 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your action method of your Web API and the definition of the model you are returning?

Comment: public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

Comment: public IEnumerable<User>GetUserList(){ return userlist}. can we do with keyvalue pair

Comment: Added your code snippets to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the format of your Json to be in a certain way then all you have to do is make sure your C# (or your .net language of choice) matches what you want to see.

In your example then the Json:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "users": [
                { "id": 1, "name": 'Ed', "email": "ed@sencha.com" },
                { "id": 2, "name": 'Tommy', "email": "tommy@sencha.com" }
             ]
}
```

Would be represented like:

```
public class YourRootObjectName
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have to map your values to this structure. Post your Web API controller code, along with DTO classes you are using and it will be much more clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return this kind of JSON the best way would be to return a separate model which contains the indication of a success and the list of users.

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Your action method could then something like this:

```
public ResponseModel GetUserList()
{ 
    var response = new ResponseModel { Success = true, Users = userlist };
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input= [{"Id":1,"Name":"Nayas","Email":"nayas@gmail.com"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Ramesh","Email":"ramesh@gmail.com"}].

var output={}
output.success=true
output.users=input
```